# Why does creating objects with constructor execute object's method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, constructor, object-construction

Suppose I want to have three objects of type `Room`. The three objects would be `bedroom`, `livingroom` and `bathroom`. `Room` has two properties `length` and `breadth`, and one method `myFunc`. I use constructor method to create the three required objects as:

```
function Room(len, bred, myFunc) {
        this.len = 5;
        this.bred = 8;  
        this.myFunc =  alert();
}

    var bedroom = new Room();
    var livingroom = new Room(); 
    var bathroom = new Room();
```

The problem is that when I run this script `myFunc` gets executed three times displaying the alert. What I thought was that since `new` keyword converts a function into an object it must not execute that object's method -- `typeof new Room` returns `"object"`.

My question is:

- if the statement `new Room();` converts a copy of `Room()` function into an object then isn't this equvalent to object creation with literal notation? If yes then shouldn't `var bedroom = new Room();` just assign properties of *Room object* to bedroom object? Why does it execute objects method?
- How do I create objects without executing their methods?

Comment: I've soon noticed that even creating objects with literal notation executes it's method.

Comment: You're not understanding the difference between `alert()` and `alert`. This has nothing to do with creating objects.

Comment: @JLRishe I thought a function must have brackets after it's name. What does javascript do when it see `alert`? Does it replace `alert` with it's definition?

Comment: `alert` is a function, as is `function(x) { alert(x); }`. When you put parentheses after a function, the function gets executed: `alert("foo")` or `(function(x) { alert(x); })("foo")`.

Comment: @Amadan _When you put parentheses after a function, the function gets executed_ Then why doesn't `alert(x);` get executed inside `function(x) { alert(x); }`?

Comment: Because it is inside the function *definition*. It will get executed when the rest of the function gets executed. For example, `function setFoo() { foo = 3; alert("foo"); }` does not set `foo` to `3`, nor alert, until you call `setFoo()` later. Nothing inside the function *definition* gets done ever until that function is executed. But you can do `setFooByAnotherName = setFoo`, that would not execute `setFoo` - only `setFoo()` (or `setFooByAnotherName()`) would.

Comment: @Amadan Thats' exactly what I thought before asking the question. Because I know `C` language and that's how function definitions works in `C`. But here everybody said `alert()` executes `alert` function inside `Room()`. Also `myFunc = alert` is of no use because I can't call `... myFunc("hello");`.

Comment: It's not *quite* same as C, because JavaScript is object-oriented, and C isn't (and it's object-oriented in a "weird" way, different from C++, for example). The variable `this` is crucial; as is the fact that the difference between a function and a method is very flimsy. `alert` expects to be called like a method (`window.alert`; the fact that it can be called as `alert` is because there is no local variable `alert`, and `window` is the default receiver). You definitely should finish the chapter on objects in JS...

Answer (score 1):

`alert` is the function and `alert()` executes it. It has nothing to do with how objects are created.

Keep in mind that `alert` needs to be wrapped because it is written in native code foreign to JavaScript.

So it should be (with clickable example):

```js
function Room(len, bred, myFunc) {
  this.len = 5;
  this.bred = 8;
  this.myFunc = function(x) {
    alert(x)
  };
}

var bedroom = new Room();
var livingroom = new Room();
var bathroom = new Room();

bedroom.myFunc('This is the bedroom.');
```

---

### Edit:

**The main reason is that `alert` expects `this` to be bound to `window`. Meaning that the following will also work:**

`this.myFunc = alert.bind(window);`

```js
function Room(len, bred, myFunc) {
  this.len = 5;
  this.bred = 8;
  this.myFunc = alert.bind(window);
}

var bedroom = new Room();
var livingroom = new Room();
var bathroom = new Room();

bedroom.myFunc('This is the bedroom.');
```

Comment: But then how do I call `alert()` with `bedroom.myFunc`? It doesn't pop up the alert message.

Comment: `bedroom.myFunc('this is the bedroom')`

Comment: It gives the following error: _TypeError: 'alert' called on an object that does not implement interface Window._

Comment: Is this a backend project? You can only use [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) if you're working with the browser.

Comment: I am using mozila firefox console. I can use `alert()` in the consle but typing `bedroom.myFunc('this is the bedroom')` gives the error.

Comment: Or you can try this 'this.myFunc =  function(x){alert(x)};'

Comment: Yes what @Abikshek said.

Comment: So now `alert(x)` doesn't execute it !!? I am more confused now.

Comment: No, because it is inside a function definition. `function Room(...) {... alert("foo"); }` will not alert until you call `Room()` or `new Room()`; similarly, `this.myFunc = function(x) { alert(x) }` will not alert until you execute `this.myFunc("foo")`.

Comment: But in my code alert() is also inside function `Room()'s` definition.

Comment: ...and it's not executed until you do `var bedroom = new Room()`, thus executing the function that contains `alert()` call.

Comment: @Amadan So does `var bedroom = new Room()` executes `Room()` and _then_ it converts Room's copy into an object which is assigned to `bedroom`?

Comment: `new` operator does this (simplified): it will make a new object, then call the function as if it was a method on that object (i.e. with `this` being set to the new object). Thus, `var bedroom = new Room()` is roughly equal to `var bedroom = {}, saved_this = this; this = {}; Room(); this = saved_this;` (very, very, very oversimplified, as I don't want to confuse you with `.call` or `Object.create` or prototypes).

Comment: Ok please post an answer and elaborate everything in that. What I get now is that `var bedroom = new Room()` does this: `bedroom.len = 5; bedroom.bred = 8;` and finally `bedroom.myFunc = alert();` -- which calls the function `alert`.

Comment: @user31782 your code is executing the alert function when you do (); e.g. if you create a separate function `function hi(){console.log('hi');}` and assign your `this.myFunc = hi();` This will execute hi function and you will see 3 hi in console logs

Comment: As for why `this.myFunc = alert;` didn't work by itself without wrapping it, I believe it's because `alert` is a function written in native code foreign to JavaScript.

Comment: @Abhishek Suppose I have an already written function `foo(){...}` and I want to assign it to an object's property then I'll always have to rewrite the whole definition inside the object's definition?

Comment: No. you can assign `foo` to that object property. `obj.property = foo;` [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/1a7djyhv/) a fiddler.

Comment: Ok, I just need to drop the brackets `()` in assignment operations. But not with `alert`.

Comment: Also the case for `window.confirm` and `window.prompt`.

Comment: This question and answer + comments consumed a lot of network bandwidth (http calls) and some amount of space in stackoverflow's content repository. @user31782 you should really accept this answer now :)

Comment: @Abhishek I still don't know what does `var bedroom = new Room();` exactly do. I need to finish MDN tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the function during assignment, that is why you see three executions with that code.
Simply replace your assignment to the function name itself:

```
function Room(len, bred, myFunc) {
        this.len = 5;
        this.bred = 8;  
        this.myFunc =  alert;
}

    var bedroom = new Room();
    var livingroom = new Room(); 
    var bathroom = new Room();
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use brackets with alert. Brackets cause the alert to be executed. If you omit brackets, then a function alert will be assigned to your myFunc property.